# Changing the variables of a class in OOP in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have defined a function called Node which stores the properties of nodes in a graph data structure. The function is something like this:

```
function Node(){
    ...
    this.outEdges = [];
    this.inEdges = [];
    ...
}
```

where the inEdges and outEdges store elements of type Edge which is another function I have defined. During the program these arrays are filled with elements.

At some point in my code I need to reset these two arrays so I write:

```
    nodes[i].outEdges.length = 0;
    nodes[i].inEdges.length = 0;
```

where nodes is an array of elements of type Node and I am accessing an element in a for loop.

The problem is, after setting outEdges and inEdges to 0, I expected them to be [] in the nodes[i] property list. However, when I output nodes[i] into console, the outEdges and inEdges still have the elements in them. The stranger thing is that when I output nodes[i].outEdges to console, it prints [] , which is correct, but clicking on [ ] again opens the list of the elements! I can't really figure out why the nodes[i] variables don't change?

Comment: In which browser are you experiencing this?

Comment: Can you add more code? Most likely where you are accessing the nodes and re-initializing is where the problem is. You can run a console check.. `var arr = [1, 2, 3]; arr.length = 0; arr //outputs []`

Comment: By itself, the process you have described in you post should work. The problem probably lies somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @Felix my random guess is IE :)

Comment: this is firefox actually!

Answer (score 1):

That happens (probably) because the browser prints out the empty array but by the time you check it, it has content again. So when you click to expand the browser shows the actual content.[image]

As you can see the values [1,3,7] were added after the command `console.log(o)` but they are shown on the screen (even though the length shown is `0`).

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to set the length field. Just re-initialize them:

```
nodes[i].outEdges = [];
nodes[i].inEdges = [];
```

**Edit:** My bad, setting the length should work. It does work for me on Chrome at least. However, I still think it's safer and better style to re-init.

Comment: Setting arrays length to 0 does reinitialize the array.

Comment: "You can set the length property to truncate an array at any time."
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: This answer is correct. Fiddling around with the array length is just asking for trouble. Just because you can set the property length to 5 (for example) that doesn't mean the array will contain 5 elements. The best way to clear an array is to just re-initialize it with the native constructor.

Comment: @AndreiNemes It's already been proven (the 2 comments before you) that it's a valid way to clear an array by setting its `length` as 0. And yes, setting an array's length as 5 will make it contain 5 elements. If an array already has items in it and you set its length as smaller, it truncates it. If you set its length as bigger than what it has, it fills it in with `undefined`.

Comment: @Andrei: The specification explicitly states that if the length is set to a smaller length than the current one, all elements with a higher index should be deleted. Truncating the length can be much more memory efficient than creating a new array.

Comment: @Ian you are wrong even according to MDN documentation:
_You can set the length property to truncate an array at any time. When you extend an array by changing its length property, the number of actual elements does not increase; for example, if you set length to 3 when it is currently 2, the array still contains only 2 elements._

Comment: It's still code smell to set the `length` property IMO (didn't vote)

Comment: @AndreiNemes it will contain three elements: the original two, and `undefined`.

Comment: @Felix Kling how is truncating faster than defining a blank array? Have you got any evidence to back that up? Even a [simple test](http://jsperf.com/trunc-vs-create) shows creating a blank array to be faster

Comment: @AndreiNemes Okay, well try it in a console.

Comment: @Andrei: I didn't say faster. I said more *memory efficient*, since you are not creating a new array instance and waiting for the garbage collector to collect the old one.

Comment: @FelixKling What does that even mean? How can you prove it's more _memory efficient_?

Comment: @AndreiNemes You're **creating** with `[]`. You're **removing** with `.length = 0`

Comment: @Andrei: You can use Chrome's developer tools and create heap snapshots and have a look at the timeline tool, how much memory is used and freed with the garbage collector. But isn't it obvious that the fewer objects you create, the less memory you use?

Comment: @FelixKling It's not obvious at all. Truncating involves going through the indices and deleting the ones greater than the length, whilst creating a new array just points the variable to a new object. Whilst it's arguable to be less memory efficient because it involves a constructor, it's still cleaner and a lot faster to use.

Comment: @FelixKling Those of us with common sense and reasoning understand you/the concept

Answer (score -1):

Just create a new object with the same name

```
nodes[i].outEdges = new Array();
```

Comment: That's a bad way to create an array in javascript.

Comment: Why? I do the same thing with Objects (var obj = new Object()) I learned JS from MDN not a text book so I decided it was good after seeing it in the wiki: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @Chris.Stover Well, when you create an array using `new Array()` it tells the interpreter to look for the `Array` constructor in the execution context and call it to generate a new object, adding a bit of overhead to the process. On the other hand, `[]` instantly creates a new runtime Array.

Comment: @Chris.Stover It's technically slower, and it's possible to override the `Array` constructor. I didn't downvote, but it's preferred to use `[]`. It's also confusing when specifying one parameter to `Array`. If it's a number, the generated array will be an array as the size of what the parameter was. For example, `new Array(50)` will be an array with 50 `undefined` items. `[50]` creates an array with `50` in it. `Array` *can* cause confusion, when `[]` is consistent.

Comment: @Chris.Stover they don't seem to advocate the use of the constructor. they seem to actually advocate `[...]` instead. The only thing the constructor is good for is the `... = Array(int)` signature (which hints how much should be preallocated for the array). Note that anything starting with `new` is actually an object rather than a primitive value. This affects `typeof` and falsity checks (all objects are truthy).